Apache Camel | Identifying the end of stream while splitting a huge xml processing in streaming mode
I have a huge xml in the file system:
I'm splitting it and processing every chunk in parallel.
It works pretty well. However, I need to understand the point at which the end of file has reached and the stream has ended so I can react to it accordingly.
This is my current route.
    from("file:/data?fileName=huge_xml.xml&noop=true")
            .split().xtokenize("//my_node", 'i', new Namespaces("", "http://www.mynamespace.com/201907/"))
            .parallelProcessing().parallelAggregate()
            .streaming()
            .process(exchange -> System.out.println(exchange.getMessage().getBody()))
            .to("direct:endOFStream");

But currently the endOFStream is called for every chunk (I suppose). I want that to be called only once when all the nodes have been successfully streamed.
What's missing there?

You need to use end() to separate the processors executed for each split from the processors to execute after the splitter completed.
